# Best practices: Calling GetInstance method to instantiate object

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

Lets discuss one thing:
I have some simple interface:

```
public interface ICar
{
    void StartEngine();
    void StopEngine();
}

public interface IRadio
{
    //doesn't matter
}
```

and some implementation:

```
public class SportCar : ICar
{
  private IRadio radio;
  public SportCar(IRadio radioObj)
  {
    radio = radioObj;
  }
  //all the rest goes here    
}
```

also we have our StructureMap initialization code, and we calling it on Program initialization:

```
private void InitializeStructureMap()
{
  ObjectFactory.Initialize(x=>
  {
     x.For<ICar>.Use<SportCar>();
     x.For<IRadio>.Use<CarAudioSystem>();
  });
 }
```

And my question is: what is the best practice to instantiate SportCar? Is calling:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICar>()
```

a good practice (now I don't now other way to resolve this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectFactory.GetInstance is your starting point, that is what you use to resolve the first object in the hierarcy.

This is how i start my WinForms applications, the same technique should apply to WebForms, Windows Services and Console Applications:

```
 var main = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Main>();
 Application.Run(main);
```

For ASP.NET MVC the framework allows you to register a factory that creates your controllers, but even in that factory you would call ObjectFactory.GetInstance to instanciate your controller.

As a side note: 
When you do initialization, you don't explicitly need to map ICar to SportCar unless you have multiple ICar implementations, you can just do

```
x.Scan(a => { a.TheCallingAssembly(); a.WithDefaultConventions(); });
```

which wil map your interfaces with default implementations.

Comment: I'm only asking for Object Initialization tips - this is only sample code so please feel free to answer me at Object Initialization topic.